# Элемент массива, найти ошибку

Tags: java

Есть массив utu, как можно проверить, что в utu[0] содержится число или символ?
Исправьте, если я где-то не прав, у меня почему-то не заходит в if, что бы я ни вводил в utu[0].
Если можно, напишите пример кода. Заранее спасибо.

```
char utu [] = textField3.getText().toCharArray();
if (Character.isDigit(utu[0])==true )
{

textField1.setText("true \n"+utu[0]);
}
```

В каких ячейках массива содержится числа, на символы проверять не обязательно, мне главное знать, где числа.

Comment: эх... неужели непонятно? для того чтоб правильно вам ответить людям надо знать или попытатся угадать что вы пытаетесь сделать. т.е вашу задачу на более высоком уровне а не конкретно в этих двух строчках. 

только зная это можно будет предлагаль варианты. 

напр:
как проверить что вводеная строка содержит только символы  
как проверить что введенная строка отвечает какому-то формату
как проверить/найти в строке допустимые/недопыстимые символы

Comment: 1. utu[] вообще что-нибудь содержит перед if-ом?
2. Вместо `Character.isDigit(utu[0])==true` достаточно написать `Character.isDigit(utu[0])`.

Answer (score 2):

```
    public class IsDigit
    {
        public static void main ( final String[] args )
        {
            final String string = "he110 w0r1d" ;
            final char[] array = string.toCharArray () ;
            for ( int i = 0 ; i < array.length ; i++ )
            {
                System.out.println ( "'" + array[i] + "'; is digit = " + Character.isDigit ( array[i] ) ) ;
            }
        }
    }
```

выводит следующее:

```
'h'; is digit = false  
'e'; is digit = false  
'1'; is digit = true  
'1'; is digit = true  
'0'; is digit = true  
' '; is digit = false  
'w'; is digit = false  
'0'; is digit = true  
'r'; is digit = false  
'1'; is digit = true  
'd'; is digit = false
```

Answer (score 1):

а может попробовать с помущу  цикла case

- utu [0]="1": тогда то...
- utu [1]="2": тогда то...
- ...
- utu [8]="9": тогда то...

Comment: Не надо так. Есть нормальное стандартное средство.